# How to compute the Delta E between two images using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I'm currently trying to determine the color difference between our output image and a painting of Monet with Python using OpenCV.

With my research I've seen that Delta E is the best for determining color difference. I've tried using extracting the BGR Channels of the two images and then taking the mean "Blue" "Green" and "Red" color used to use for computing the difference of each color channel.

```
output_chans = cv2.split(image)
monet_chans = cv2.split(best_painting)
colors = ("Blue", "Green", "Red")

for (output_chan, monet_chan, color) in zip(output_chans, monet_chans, colors):
    output_mean = np.mean(output_chan)
    monet_mean = np.mean(monet_chan)

    color1_rgb = None
    color2_rgb = None

    if color == "Blue":
            color1_rgb = sRGBColor(0.0, 0.0, output_mean)
            color2_rgb = sRGBColor(0.0, 0.0, monet_mean)
    elif color == "Green":
            color1_rgb = sRGBColor(0.0, output_mean, 0.0);
            color2_rgb = sRGBColor(0.0, monet_mean, 0.0);
    elif color == "Red":
            color1_rgb = sRGBColor(output_mean, 0.0, 0.0);
            color2_rgb = sRGBColor(monet_mean, 0.0, 0.0);

    # Convert from RGB to Lab Color Space
    color1_lab = convert_color(color1_rgb, LabColor);

    # Convert from RGB to Lab Color Space
    color2_lab = convert_color(color2_rgb, LabColor);

    # Find the color difference
    delta_e = delta_e_cie2000(color1_lab, color2_lab);

    print("Delta E of the Mean of %s Channel: %f" % (color, delta_e))
```

I receive an output of for the color difference for each color channel, however my professor suggests that I may be doing Delta E wrong as I'm supposed to only get one value for the color difference of the entire image instead of one value for each three color channels. In this case is there an alternative method or a correct method of of calculating the Delta E of our two images?

This is a link to a sample of our test image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjM5B.jpg

And a link to a sample of the paintings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5WW6.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you seem to be using the `colormath` library which does the math nicely, but is very slow.  the [`colour-science` package](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) uses numpy to vectorise operations and get an answer in much less time

the `cv2` library you're using has simple versions of some of the transformations you need, e.g. you can get most of the way doing:

```
import cv2

image1_rgb = cv2.imread('image1.jpeg')
image2_rgb = cv2.imread('image2.jpeg')

image1_lab = cv2.cvtColor(image1_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)
image2_lab = cv2.cvtColor(image2_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)
```

but note that you'll probably get better results if you convert to floats first:

```
image_lab = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb.astype(np.float32) / 255, cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)
```

and then just use `color-science` for the final call to [`delta_E()`](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/colour.delta_E.html) for each pixel (but note these are all vectorised, so you just give it the array of everything and it does it all efficiently at once):

```
import colour

delta_E = colour.delta_E(image1_lab, image2_lab)
```

and then you'll probably want the mean of this over the whole image:

```
np.mean(delta_E)
```

but median, quantiles, or a plotting the distribution would give you more information

note that if you care about color spaces and need more control over the transform from RGB to Lab you get a lot more control with `colour-science`, with the rough template looking like:

```
image_lab = colour.XYZ_to_Lab(colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(image_srgb))
```

and there are lots of options about how to do this transform along the way, see docs for [`colour.XYZ_to_Lab`](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/colour.sRGB_to_XYZ.html) and [`colour.XYZ_to_Lab`](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/colour.XYZ_to_Lab.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this in pure opencv? :\

Comment: @jtlz2 could point me to a "Delta E" calculation in OpenCV? if so then I'll try and update my answer, but AFAICT it doesn't include that functionality at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. However, if you are looking for more simplified way for calculating Delta E, i.e. by avoiding extra dependencies. You can simply calculate calculate the Euclidean distance between the two images and take mean.

```
def deltaE(img1, img2, colorspace = cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB):
   # check the two images are of the same size, else resize the two images
   (h1, w1) = img1.shape[:2]
   (h2, w2) = img1.shape[:2]
    h, w = None, None
    # check the height
    if h1 > h2:
        h = h1
    else:
        h = h2
    #check the width
    if w1 > w2:
        w = w1
    else:
        w = w2
    
    img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (h,w))
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (h,w))
    # Convert BGR images to specified colorspace
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, colorspace)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, colorspace)
    # compute the Euclidean distance with pixels of two images 
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((img1 - img2) ** 2, axis=-1))/255.
```

Comment: The deltaE is not always an Euclidean distance though. CIE 2000 is a pretty long expression.