# How can I calculate the colorspace Delta E in python using only OpenCV/numpy/scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I am trying to calculate *Delta E* (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIELAB_%CE%94E*)) in order to measure the color/colour difference between two different images.

I am following the method at [How to compute the Delta E between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224007/how-to-compute-the-delta-e-between-two-images), but (partly in order to reduce dependencies on other libraries), I would like to calculate *Delta E* in python using only opencv (and/or numpy/scipy) and its dependencies.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is pretty straightforward. Just compute the math from the Wikipedia reference. Here is a Python/OpenCV/Numpy only solution.

Input A:

[image]

Input B:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image_A and convert to float
image_A = cv2.imread('barn.jpg').astype("float32")

# read image_B as grayscale and convert to float
image_B = cv2.imread('barn_mod.jpg').astype("float32")

# convert image_A and image_B from BGR to LAB
image_A = cv2.cvtColor(image_A,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) 
image_B = cv2.cvtColor(image_B,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) 

# compute difference
diff = cv2.add(image_A,-image_B)

# separate into L,A,B channel diffs
diff_L = diff[:,:,0]
diff_A = diff[:,:,1]
diff_B = diff[:,:,2]

# compute delta_e as mean over every pixel using equation from  
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIELAB_ΔE*
delta_e = np.mean( np.sqrt(diff_L*diff_L + diff_A*diff_A + diff_B*diff_B) )

# print results
print (delta_e)
```

delta_e:

```
0.29771116
```

See also:

https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delta_e.html

https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/colormath/color_diff.html

https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/color/delta_e.py